# Missing "Ignore" option in VCS window

Tags: version-control, rider

I'm going through Rider tutorials and VCS tutorial seems to claim that upon right-clicking on the unstaged file/directory there should be an option to add it to ignore list; however it's missing in my case (see screenshot).

[Screenshot from tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE0CL.png)

Git plugin is enabled. Is there any option I need enabled in VCS settings that I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2019.2, Rider's VCS client was updated so that you can now ignore files using the native Git mechanism of `.gitignore` files. Unfortunately this tutorial was not updated accordingly.

We'll update the tutorial in the next version. In the meantime, you can find the up-to-date version of this tutorial in [Rider's online help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/2019.2/Get_Started_with_Version_Control.html).